# Powershell - Calling Function From Another Function

Tags: powershell

In Powers shell V4 is it okay to call a function from another function? I'm I doing something that is bad practice if I do it that way?

Assume I have these two functions:

```
  function secondFunction($username){
         Write-Out "The Next Step is...."
    }

 function myFunction($username){
  Write-Output Welcome $username
  secondFunction($userName)
}
```

Is the above code okay to do? What are the disadvantages of doing so?

Comment: Nothing wrong with that... Can you  be more specific?

Comment: The is nothing wrong except that `secondFunction`  should be declared before `myFunction` else this will not work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PowerShell ideal, that is to say the way that your functions should exist is to be their own islands.  They can be built off of calling an infinite number of cmdlets, and run a number of lines of code, but for simplicity and supportability sake, they should stand alone.

Is it possible for you to attack this a different way, so that you can have a single pipe-line which achieves the same result, something like:

```
myFunction (outputs an object $username with props) | secondFunction (accepts pipeline input and does the second step)
```

This would be a lot easier to understand for most people to troubleshoot and support once you're done with these tools.

That being said, it's not violating a cardinal rule that I know of to call a function from within your funciton, but I would recommend being explicit about this in the help for your functions if you have to go this route.

Comment: I don't really agree with this generalization. If you write a module filled with functions, why wouldn't want to try to avoid using those functions in other functions? Isn't that part of the benefit of being able to choose which functions are exported in a module and which aren't so you can hide the "private" or "helper" functions? To say every function should be "an island" is silly to me as it promotes the creation of big ugly "spaghetti code" functions.

Comment: I hear what you're saying, and wouldn't encourage anyone to make repetitive spaghetti code. Still, the core backbone of PowerShell is all about the pipeline and making small targeted tools that do a particular function. If the OP were to approach his problem with the intent to make 'powershell styled' tolls and come up with a pipeline based approach to using his functions, I think it would be the best of both worlds, functionally and ideally.

Comment: Ok, I would agree with that too!